# NullPointerException when attempting to use .setText on a Text object

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

Whenever I try to use .setText on the Text field in my controller class, I get a NullPointerException.
Here is my controller class:

```
public class ViewTripController{

    private static File open;

    private static Trip trip; 

    @FXML
    static Text budget;

    @FXML
    static Text spent;


    @FXML
    void toEditTrip(){
        VistaNavigator.loadVista(VistaNavigator.EDIT_TRIP);
    }

    @FXML
    void toAddExpense(){
        VistaNavigator.loadVista(VistaNavigator.EDIT_TRIP);
    }

    public static void setTrip(Trip trip2){
        trip = trip2;
    }


    public static void budgetText(String text){
        budget.setText(text);
    }

    public static void spentText(String text){
        spent.setText(text);
    }

    public static void setFile(File file){
        open = file;
    }
}
```

Here is my FXML file:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<StackPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafx.ViewTripController">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Text layoutX="68.0" layoutY="87.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Total Budget: " />
            <Text layoutX="68.0" layoutY="136.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Total Spent: " />
            <Button layoutX="109.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toEditTrip" text="Add Expense..." />
            <Button layoutX="373.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="View Expense List" />
            <Text fx:id="budget" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="87.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
            <Text fx:id="spent" layoutX="133.0" layoutY="136.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
         </children></Pane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

When I looked at other posts, they've told me to check the `fx:id` in the FXML objects. I've done this and the `fx:id`s are all correct. Why would I be getting a NullPointerException here?

Comment: FXML Injected members should not be static. Remove all `static` keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` does not consider static fields as valid injection targets. The fields therefore need to be non-static. If you need to access them in a static way (which you should avoid), you could still copy the values to static fields in the `initialize` method.

You can find alternatives to using static fields for passing information here: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)